# combine a byte into long long

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I have a int64 (which is a long long)  value and a byte value. I want to merge them together. i know that my long long value doesn't use 64 bits. So i want to use the unset 8 bits (most significant or least significant?) to encode a byte into it.

Later on i want to seperate them to find the original value and the byte.

so preferably  functions or a macros of sort

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef long long int64;

int64 make_global_rowid(int64 rowid, byte hp_id);

byte get_hp_id(int64 global_row_id);

int64 get_row_id(int64 global_row_id);
```

get_hp_id seperates and returns the byte from the merged value, while the get_row_id returns the original int64 which was merged with the byte

Comment: and how far have you got so far with your coding this? p.s. you can do it with & (and operator) and bitshifts <<, >>

Comment: Could be useful to have the `|` or operator too... ;)

Comment: The function names are just mentioned to clarify what i want to achieve. if i knew how to do it, i would not be here :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bitwise operators to achieve this. Let's say you want to sacrifice the 8 most significant bits in your long long. (Be careful if your long long is negative ! The sign is stored as the most significant bit, so you'll lose the sign !)

Now, to do this, you can do :

```
byte get_hp_id(int64 global_row_id)
{
  return ((char)global_row_id);
}

int64 get_row_id(int64 global_row_id)
{
  return (global_row_id >> 8);
}

int64 make_global_rowid(int64 rowid, byte hp_id)
{
  return (rowid << 8 + hp_id)
}
```

For the little explanation, `<<` is a bitshifting operator. What it does is that it shifts all your bits either right or left. Bits that goes out of boundaries are lost, and bits coming from nowhere are set to 0 :

```
 1001001 << 2 == 0100100 // the first 1 is lost, and 2 "0" come from the right
```

In your case, we shift to the right of 8 bits (to leave space for your byte), and therefore the 8 most significant bits are lost forever.
But now, we have something like :

```
(xxxxxxxx)(xxxxxxxx)(xxxxxxxx)(00000000)
```

Which means that we can add anything fitting in 8 bits without modifying the original value. And tada ! We have stored a byte in a long long !

Now, to extract the byte, you can just cast it as a char. During the cast, only the 8 least significant bits are saved (your byte).

And finally, to extract your long long, you just have to shift the bits the other way around. The byte will be overwritten, and your long long will be as good as new !

Comment: 'and bits coming from nowhere are set to 0': that's true for `<<`, but not necessarily for `>>`.  If the values are all guaranteed non-negative, something like this will work.  If negatives may be present, on the other hand, it becomes a lot more complex.

Comment: I thought that the value was filled with 0 no matter what shift is used? Why is it different for ```>>```? As for the negatives, I'll edit to mention it :)

Comment: I just tested, and it is filled with 0 when compiled with gcc. Is it system dependant? (I also learned that shifting the size of your variable (e.g. shifting an int32 of 32 bits) trigger a compilation warning, and no shifting is done in that case. Strange...)

Comment: For unsigned, `>>` always shifts in 0.  For signed, it is implementation dependent whether it shifts in 0 or the sign.  (As a general rule, when shifting and using bit-ops, you're better off using unsigned types.)

Comment: If an element has `n` bits, any shift outside the range `[0...n)` is undefined behavior.  The reason is basically that some hardware will load the shift count into a 5 bit internal register (on a 32 bit machine), and the standard didn't want to impose any checks on the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint about bit operations in C:

```
   int i = 0x081500; //lsb is 0x00
   char b = '\x12';   //any byte
   char r;

   i = i | ( b & 0xff );     // will be 0x081512
   r = i & 0xff;  // again 0x12, equal to r

   i = i | ( (b & 0xff) << 16 ); // will be 0x120815000 because first b is shifted 16 bits (--> 0x120000)
   r = ( i >> 16 ) & 0xff;  // first i is shifted to 0x12, then use lsb
   /* important: this expects i >= 0 */
```

Same works with long or long long as well of course. I hope that helps you to understand how to use bit operations.

Comment: `>>` isn't rigorously specified with signed.

Comment: @Jams Kanze: you're right of course. Masking b with 0xff should do. I have edited my code accordingly

Comment: @James I'd better read carefully before answering (it's getting late here :-). Nevertheless you're right. The code was to be an example on how bit operations work, I will add a comment that `i` is to be excepted to be >= 0

Answer (score 0):

for the sake of ease of use I would use a union:

```
union longlong_and_byte {
    long long long_value;
    char char_values[8];
};

union longlong_and_byte test;

test.long_value = 4000;

// for little endian (x86 for example) the most significant byte is the last one
test.char_values[7] = 19;

// for big endian (PPC for example) the most significant byte is the first one
test.char_values[0] = 19;


printf("long long value is %ld\nchar value is %d\n"
, test.long_value & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF // need to mask off the necessary bits, only works with unsigned
, test.char_values[7]
);
```

Comment: That's undefined behavior.  In practice, it will be implementation dependent, depending on endianness (unless he ports to a real exotic, where it could cause later crashes and such).